# Can you tile over blueboard?

Tags: bathroom, drywall

I'm doing a bathroom remodel and want to tile the entire bathroom (not just the bath/wet area) floor to ceiling.

[image: bathroom]

My contractor used concrete board in the bath area (which sounds good), but used blueboard in the non-bath area. He says the blueboard should be good enough for tiling from floor to ceiling, even with heavy porcelain tile. Is this true? Would you recommend just using concrete board throughout?

Comment: A moderator made an edit to say "water-resistant drywall" in the title, however this question is specifically about blueboard (which I believe isn't even water-resistant)

Comment: E.g. this article describes blueboard, so I believe it's a term experienced builders will understand: http://www.doityourself.com/stry/cement-board-vs-greenboard-or-blueboard

Comment: Fair enough. I guess my experience didn't ever involve preparing for new plaster. FYI, moderators don't make changes at SE. Users of all stripes do. It's a community-proctored network.

Comment: Tile everywhere in the bathroom seems like overdoing a good thing. Water impervious wallpaper used to be be used in bathrooms and worked well. This also allows for redesign/redecorating if you are careful to use 'strippable' wallpaper. Another possibility is to texture and then use a good quality waterproof primer followed by good quality final coat of paint.

Comment: @JimStewart Thanks for the comment! Agreed. It's more of an aesthetic decision instead of water-proofing related. Tiling the entire bathroom floor-to-ceiling is popular now in modern designs. The very difficult part is in selecting correct tile so that it doesn't look like "too much." For example this may be a good look for a larger-size bathroom: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Jr_csgUm_F4/VA2V_c3vQTI/AAAAAAAAYkk/QS5Kw9FFsYg/s1600/beautiful-bathroom-wall-tiles-designs-ideas-for-modern-bathroom.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Tile will hold up fine on the blue board / green board in areas that are not wet. in the 50's it was common to install tile on regular sheetrock in bath / shower areas. I saw many jobs that lasted 20-30 years before the sheetrock failed in wet areas but in dry areas it last longer (than wet areas)and is less expensive to install.

Answer (score 1):

That's fine. I sure hope there's some waterproofing in the shower stall, though--either in the form of poly sheeting behind the cementboard, or a plan to apply paint-on waterproofing membrane like RedGard over it. Tile and cementboard are not waterproof.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. They didn't use a membrane/sheeting, fortunately it (looks like) GoBoard is waterproof as long as seams are sealed properly: https://www.jm.com/en/home-insulation/tile-backer-board/goboard/

Comment: Oh, that's cool!